# &center causes ¢ sign to come in PHP

Tags: php

I want to save an url with parameters to a string.
One of the parameters is "center".

However, when I try to save it as `www.xyz.com?r=1&center=34`, it reads it as `www.xyz.com?r=1¢er=34`. I do not want to convert `&cent` to the cent sign. What is the proper procedure to do this?

Edit: Since this is receiving negative votes, I'd like to mention that in my case, I actually needed the raw string instead of escaping it. It is working now. Rendering on the HTML page was a problem, but the `file_get_contents` needed the exact url, and it is working.

If you still wish to downvote this question, please explain why.

Comment: Escape your url parameters appropriately. `&` when rendered on a page should be `&amp;`

Comment: It would cause `file_get_contents` to not work when I later parse this URL if I use `&amp;`

Comment: Then you need to update your question explaining that (and providing more details). Your question as asked is solved by writing valid HTML.

Comment: @The negative voter, care to explain why?

Answer (score 0):

Try this way,

```
$link = "www.xyz.com?r=1&center=34";
$result = str_replace("&", "&amp;", $link);
echo $result;
```

Answer (score 0):

It's because `&something;` is the HTML way of "escaping". Here are a few examples:

- `&copy;`: ©
- `&times;`: ×
- `&euro;`: €
- `&larr;`: ← (left arrow)
- `&rarr;`: → (right arrow)
- `&amp;`: & (the actual sign)

You can find more of those on [w3schools](https://www.w3schools.com/html/html_symbols.asp).

It's because you have to escape the `&` in URLs: `&amp;`.

So, in your URL, you should replace that lonely `&` by `&amp;`.It should look like this:

```
www.xyz.com?r=1&amp;center=43
```